# Instantiate an engine from a second project without having a reference to the second project causing a circular reference?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, distributed-development

Let's talk about three projects. I have a `Cinema` project, a `Cinema.Engine` project, and a `Cinema.Client1` project.

In the `Cinema` project, I have an interface `ICinema` and a factory class `CinemaFactory`.

In the `Cinema.Engine` project, I have a class that implements `ICinema`... we'll call it `CinemaEngine : ICinema`. This project is exposed as a WCF service referencing the `Cinema` project.

This allows my `Cinema.Client1` project to only reference the `Cinema` project. The `Cinema.Client1` can call the `CinemaFactory` and obtain a reference to the `ICinema` provided by the WCF service. All is well and good....... Now to get icky.

Let's add a fourth project called `Cinema.Client2` which has references to both the `Cinema` and `Cinema.Engine` projects. Because I have a reference to `Cinema.Engine`, I want to be able to call my factory with a different set of parameters and have the factory instantiate the engine locally instead of calling the WCF service.

Important note: the `Cinema` project does not have any references to any other projects.

So, if I only have a reference to the `Cinema` project, then the factory should look like this:

```
public class CinemaFactory {
    public ICinema GetCinema (Uri RemoteCinema) {}
}
```

But if I have a reference to `Cinema.Engine` then the factory should look like this:

```
public class CinameFactory {
    public ICinema GetCinema (string CinemaParameters) {}
}
```

To put it another way:
The client (residing in one project) needs to obtain an instance of the engine (residing in a second project). That instance will either be a proxy to a WCF service or it will be instantiated locally. This instance will be obtained from a factory (residing in a third project). The first project (containing the client) and the third project (containing the engine) both reference the second project (containing the factory).

If the client is obtaining the proxy, it shouldn't need a reference to the second project. If the client has a reference to the second project, only then should the factory provide the option of instantiating the engine locally.

How can I get the factory (in the third project) to instantiate the engine locally (from the second project) without having a reference to the second project (which causes a circular reference)?

Things I've looked into but that don't work:

- Partial classes don't work. Partial classes are syntactic sugar and
  cannot span projects.
- Same class, different namespace (for the factory): but how would I know which namespace to pull the class from?
- `new` keyword: only applies to members, not to entire classes.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working here?

Comment: Ok, your factory needs two entry points, one with an `Uri` and one with a `string` as a parameter. Where is the problem?

Comment: If the problem boils down to having two different signatures, why don't you use the `string` signature, pass a `string` in the first example, and convert it to a `Uri` when it arrives? `Uri` has a constructor overload that accepts a string.  Your other alternative is to have two method signatures in your `Interface`.

Comment: The problem is that if I add and implement  the second entry point to `Cinema.CinemaFactory`, then I must also have a reference to the `Cinema.Engine` project. Not only does this cause a circular reference, but it means deploying the `Cinema.Engine.dll` file along with my client, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Where do you keep your `Interface`s in your client?  Specifically, `ICinema`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the `Interface`s are all in the `Cinema` project. (As are DTOs.) It's layered architecture specifically for distributed deployment: `Cinema.Engine` supplies the business logic. `Cinema` provides the facade so that the client layer knows what it's working with.

Comment: Why does adding the second entry point require a new reference to `Cinema.Engine` in the client?  Can't you just alter the existing `ICinema` interface, or add a new interface in the same location?

Comment: The entry point doesn't require a reference. The *implementation* of that entry point requires a reference. And we're not talking about the `ICinema` interface, we're talking about the factory class. .... I'll expand: The client will either 1) obtain a reference to the engine from a WCF endpoint or it will 2) instantiate the engine locally [sic]. Both options are accomplished using the factory. (Isn't that what factories are for?) But the second option should only be available if the client has a reference to the project containing the engine. (more to come)

Comment: The factory can't instantiate the engine without having a reference to the engine's project. The engine's project already has a reference to the project containing the factory (because that project also contains the interface that the engine implements).

Comment: Maybe you should consider to move the factory class in a different project.

Comment: Well, you either need the functionality in `Cinema.Engine` or you don't.  If you need that functionality, then you need to take a reference to it.  As Adrian suggests, you can also move that functionality somewhere else if you don't want to take a reference to `Cinema.Engine`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what extension methods are for. I can define the factory in the `Cinema` project with just the one method signature. I can define an extension method in `Cinema.Engine`.

Sample code below, showing how to accomplish this using extension methods. The four namespaces are meant to reside in four different projects.

```
namespace Cinema {

    // Required for WCF
    public interface ICinema {
    }

    public sealed class CinemaFactory {
        // Singleton pattern to support extension methods. (Can't add extension methods to static classes.)
        private static readonly Lazy<CinemaFactory> LazyInstance = new Lazy<CinemaFactory> (() => new CinemaFactory());

        public static CinemaFactory Instance {
        get {
                return LazyInstance.Value;
            }
        }

        private CinemaFactory () {
        }

        public ICinema  GetCinema (EndpointAddress10 RemoteCinemaUri) {
            ICinema CinemaEngineInstance;

            // Get a reference from the WCF service...

            return CinemaEngineInstance;
        }
    }
}

namespace Cinema.Engine {
    using Cinema;

    public class CinemaEngine : ICinema {
    }

    // Add polymorphism to the class defined in a different project.
    public static class CinemaFactoryHelper {
        public static ICinema GetCinema (this CinemaFactory _This) {
            return new CinemaEngine ();
        }
    }
}

namespace Cinema.Client1 {
    using Cinema;

    public class Consumer1 {
        // Intellisense shows that there are no overloads to the GetCinema() method. Yay!
        private ICinema ref = CinemaFactory.Instance.GetCinema (EndpointAddress10.FromEndpointAddress (new EndpointAddress ("http://localhost"));
    }
}

namespace Cinema.Client2 {
    using Cinema;
    using Cinema.Engine; // Add visibility to the extension method that provides a local instance of the engine.

    public class Consumer2 {
        // Intellisense shows the method +1 overload. Yay!
        private ICinema ref = CinemaFactory.Instance.GetCinema ();
    }
}
```

Comment: So your `ICinema` interface is now empty? `O_o`

Comment: :P The contents of the `ICinema` interface are not relevant to the functionality of the factory which was the original subject of the question.

Comment: The `CinemaEngine` is exposed as a WCF service. You can't create a WCF service without an interface. It's precisely the interface that gets exposed. Thus, I need the interface.

Comment: Well, +1 for creativity.  I love extension methods.

Comment: Let's look at it this way: The `Cinema` project defines _what_ the client is working with and _how_ to gain access to it. The `Cinema.Engine` project handles all of the implementation. The two client projects simply consume it. And since the implementation might be hidden behind a WCF service, the client _might not_ need a reference to the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have something like this:

```
public interface IWidget {}

public class RemoteWidget : IWidget {}
public class LocalWidget : IWidget {}

public class WidgetFactory
{
  public IWidget Create(Configuration configuration)
  {
      return new LocalWidget(configuration);
  }

  public IWidget Create(Uri origin)
  {
      return new RemoteWidget(origin);
  }
}
```

And, for some reason, you now want to distribute `WidgetFactory` separately from `LocalWidget`. How do you create a `WidgetFactory` that doesn't know at compile-time which `IWdidget` implementations are available or where to find them?

You've got a few options. For example:

- Scan an extensions, modules, or plugins directory for DLL's and [load them dynamically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Use a [DI framework](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=.net+di+frameworks) that can do some of that dynamic library loading for you.
- Use the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.100).aspx).
- [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) ... *maybe*. I just get the sense this might work; I can't think of *how* offhand.
- Let the client application configure `WidgetFactory` or register the available `Widget` implementations. This is probably the path of least assumption: The client can choose to use DI, MEF, extensions methods, direct reflection, etc. You're not imposing much in terms of architecture this way.
- Similarly, make your `WidgetFactory.Create` accept a `Type` parameter (potentially as a Generic). In your case, your client seems to need to know which type it needs built *anyway*. So, this may be acceptable ...

***OR***, just change your design: Don't treat the "Widgets" project as your distributable; include it in your distributable. In that case, you wouldn't put a `WidgetFactory` in the "Widgets" project, you'd put an `IWidgetFactory` in.

Then, either ask the client to provide the concrete factory, or create a few distro's based on your pricing model (I'm assuming that's what's driving the need for separation). E.g., `FreeDistro`, `StandardDistro`, `EnterpriseDistro` ... Each of those distros would just include hard references to the concrete types (and factories) available at that "support level."

Lots of options... Not all mutually exclusive options either!

Comment: While I appreciate your answer and the effort you put into it, I had an epiphany at lunch and beat you to the answer by about a half hour. I pasted [code on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/PLeKGJTr) that hopefully explains how to do it with extension methods. The four namespaces are meant to reside in four different projects.